# Need to continuosly obtain gps coordinates for a particular range in Android

Tags: android, gps, location

I need to obtain coordinates for my application...I am doing this by using LocationManager

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Now i need to perform the following Task :-

1. If suppose the option of "Use GPS Option is Unchecked" then i need to enable it
2. I need to obtain location coordinates for a particular range.. Like suppose if i get current coordinate as something then the mobile keep on getting the locations till 100 meters of that current location obtained
3. Is there any other good solution of obtaining coordinates apart from LocationManager..Like some open source SDK to obtain it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use requestLocationUpdates and removeUpdates while check/uncheck on the checkbox you provided.
2. Store the first location coordinate and in onLocationChanged keep on checking for the distance using [distanceTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) API.
3. Not sure why you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks Pravin... I Might need something else as while requesting location updates consumes lots of Battery and my application will keep on getting the location cooerdinates all the time on location change....

Comment: Can u explain me how to use this distanceTo function

Comment: Assuming the first location you received in onLocationChanged in loc1 and the second location to which you wish to find the distance is loc2 then loc1.distanceTo(loc2) will give you the distance in metres.